# When I try to join a friend's game via Steam, it says "You have been banned from the current session"

Tags: dungeon-defenders

This only started happening after the recent patch *(7.06, came out about 10 minutes ago)*.

He of course hasn't banned me, but we can't join each others' games.  How can we fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in a hotfix tomorrow.

> - Fixed Private Match joining bug. Temporary workaround for 7.06: If you are experiencing issues joining a friends match or friend joining yours, toggle the Show/Hide Match button in the pause menu

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question so quickly, but a lot of people are having this issue *right now*.

To solve, have the host hit escape and click `Show match` in the upper-right.

I don't know why they would make the default setting *"open to the public but closed to friend's list"*...